# mule xpath extractvalue mysql

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

I have a question about extracting a value with xpath

Some part of the xml:

```
<mark:info>
    <mark:Information name="Adress" answer="SomeStreet"/>
    <mark:Information name="PhoneNumber" answer="123456789"/>
</mark:info>
```

I want to receive the text "SomeStreet" with extractValue function in mysql

I was trying to create an xpath expression like

```
//mark:info/mark:Information[@name='Adress']
```

but I'm receiving the whole node. I need just the text "SomeStreet" but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath `//mark:Information[@name="Adress"]/@answer` should give `SomeStreet`

BTW shouldn't your xml have a `xmlns` specifying what is `mark` like :

`<mark:info xmlns:mark="http://example.com">` ?